# Saving 3D+Time (XYCZT) stacks with Bio-Formats on Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, metadata, tiff

I'm having some trouble to save 3D+Time Tiff files, from Numpy arrays in Python, using the Bioformats standard.

For a start, I have a numpy array with 5 dimensions, ordered XYCZT, in my case (267, 518, 1, 331, 3).

Here is the function I have so far:

```
# Write file to disk
def write(img_XYCZT, path, type='uint16', verbose=True):

import bioformats.omexml as ome
import javabridge as jutil
import bioformats
import numpy as np
import os
import sys

if verbose:
    print('Dimensions (XYCZT): ' + str(np.shape(img_XYCZT)))
    sys.stdout.flush()

# Get the new dimensions
SizeX = np.shape(img_XYCZT)[0]
SizeY = np.shape(img_XYCZT)[1]
SizeC = np.shape(img_XYCZT)[2]
SizeZ = np.shape(img_XYCZT)[3]
SizeT = np.shape(img_XYCZT)[4]

# Start JVM for bioformats
jutil.start_vm(class_path=bioformats.JARS)

# Getting metadata info
omexml = ome.OMEXML()
omexml.image(0).Name = os.path.split(path)[1]
p = omexml.image(0).Pixels
assert isinstance(p, ome.OMEXML.Pixels)
p.SizeX = SizeX
p.SizeY = SizeY
p.SizeC = SizeC
p.SizeT = SizeT
p.SizeZ = SizeZ
p.DimensionOrder = ome.DO_XYCZT
p.PixelType = type
p.channel_count = SizeC
p.plane_count = SizeZ
p.Channel(0).SamplesPerPixel = SizeC
omexml.structured_annotations.add_original_metadata(ome.OM_SAMPLES_PER_PIXEL, str(SizeC))

# Converting to omexml
xml = omexml.to_xml()

# Write file using Bioformats
if verbose:
    print ('Writing frames:'),
    sys.stdout.flush()

for frame in range(SizeT):
    if verbose:
        print('[' + str(frame + 1) + ']'),
        sys.stdout.flush()

    index = frame

    pixel_buffer = bioformats.formatwriter.convert_pixels_to_buffer(img_XYCZT[:, :, :, :, frame], type)

    script = """
    importClass(Packages.loci.formats.services.OMEXMLService,
                Packages.loci.common.services.ServiceFactory,
                Packages.loci.formats.out.TiffWriter);

    var service = new ServiceFactory().getInstance(OMEXMLService);
    var metadata = service.createOMEXMLMetadata(xml);
    var writer = new TiffWriter();
    writer.setBigTiff(true);
    writer.setMetadataRetrieve(metadata);
    writer.setId(path);
    writer.setInterleaved(true);
    writer.saveBytes(index, buffer);
    writer.close();
    """
    jutil.run_script(script, dict(path=path, xml=xml, index=index, buffer=pixel_buffer))

if verbose:
    print ('[Done]')
    sys.stdout.flush()

if verbose:
    print('File saved on ' + str(path))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Being *img_XYCZT* the numpy array, and *path* the place to save the file. Probably the function uses lots of redundancy for the metadata, but thats me fighting for it to work somehow...

Checking the saved file on Fiji, the Z information is as C channels:
[image]

The file simply doesn't have the Z dimension... I've been struggling with this for some time, any help is highly appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Hi @delestro. The Bio-Formats forum at https://www.openmicroscopy.org/community/ might be the right place to ask, or the image.sc forum at https://forum.image.sc/